# Heartbeat Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]

Tags: linux

all
I came across some error while starting heartbeat 3.0.5, the output of the /var/log/ha-log are as following:

```
[root@localhost ha.d]# tail -200  /var/log/ha-log  
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2215]: info: Pacemaker support: false
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2215]: WARN: Logging daemon is disabled --enabling logging daemon is recommended
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2215]: info: **************************
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2215]: info: Configuration validated. Starting heartbeat 3.0.5
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: heartbeat: version 3.0.5
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: WARN: No Previous generation - starting at 1366465937
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: Heartbeat generation: 1366465937
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: No uuid found for current node - generating a new uuid.
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: Creating FIFO /usr/var/lib/heartbeat/fifo.
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: glib: UDP Broadcast heartbeat started on port 694 (694) interface eth0
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: glib: UDP Broadcast heartbeat closed on port 694 interface eth0 - Status: 1
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: glib: ucast: write socket priority set to IPTOS_LOWDELAY on eth0
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: glib: ucast: bound send socket to device: eth0
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: glib: ucast: bound receive socket to device: eth0
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: glib: ucast: started on port 694 interface eth0 to 192.168.121.152
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: glib: ping heartbeat started.
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: G_main_add_TriggerHandler: Added signal manual handler
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: G_main_add_TriggerHandler: Added signal manual handler
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: G_main_add_SignalHandler: Added signal handler for signal 17
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2223]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2224]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2225]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2226]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2228]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2222]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2227]: ERROR: Cannot chdir to [/var/lib/heartbeat/cores]: No such file or directory
Apr 20 21:52:16 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: Local status now set to: 'up'
Apr 20 21:52:17 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: Link 192.168.121.1:192.168.121.1 up.
Apr 20 21:52:17 localhost heartbeat: [2217]: info: Status update for node 192.168.121.1: status ping
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: So, does /var/lib/heartbeat/cores exist?

Comment: The folder '/var/lib/heartbeat/cores' doesn't exist, but the installation of heartbeat is all right, no errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by the following way:

1. manylly create directory: mkdir /var/lib/heartbeat/cores
2. manylly create directory: mkdir /var/lib/heartbeat/cores/root
3. manylly create directory: mkdir /var/lib/heartbeat/cores/hacluster

Heartbeat didon't create them automatically.

Thanks.